# ListView scrolling with Up/Down button click bug

Tags: android

I have a listview, which is scrollable, with dynamically items loaded from the database. And I have two buttons, "UP" for scrolling up by 100 pixels and "Down" for scrolling down by 100 pixels also.
The problem is that after I click down or up, the screen scrolls but after that all items in listview are not selectable at their right place. For example, I press down key and it scrolls well but after that I click item3 and it accepts item1 as clicked object.
I have tried `ListView.refreshDrawableState()` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the `setSelection()` method instead of scrolling the list by 100 pixels each time. Increment the selection when you're scrolling down and decrement it while scrolling up. This will assure that the right item is being clicked. Hope this helps.

Comment: @HosseinAmini, You're welcome, glad this has helped! Consider accepting the answer if you've found it useful.

Comment: @HosseinAmini, You should press the check icon at the left of the answer body to accept it. AFAIK this can be done no matter of the reputation.

Comment: thanks, i'm newbie so i am not familiar with this stuff, anyway thank u.